# PHP Symfony issue after insert(if accessed immediately)

Tags: php, symfony

I got an interesting issue and not sure how to solve it correctly.

My code

```
  $project = new Project();
  $project->setUsers($user);
  $em->persist($project);
  $em->flush();      
  $em->getConnection()->commit();
  
  return $project->getId()
```

so, this piece of code return id that was inserted

Full steps:

- front make an request to api(POST)
- API insert new project and return project id
- front make request to an get single project route(GET by id) -> and here the issue come, its say no records found

Currently, in order to work I've set an delay of 1sec on front-side between POST and GET

but how to solve this without delay, any idea?
I've tried without transaction but it did't help

- Note: issue appear periodically, usually when SQL is very busy

Comment: Your front application needs to wait the response before redirecting to the page

Comment: that's the problem, on route POST, the front get the new id of the new entity, but if immediately go to GET by that id will appear the issue mention